# Working With Data in Both A Computed Property and a Life Cycle Hook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am fairly new to VueJS and I just want to make sure that the following code is written properly (and that there is not a better way to do this).

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <section class="hero" :style="bgSrc">
    <slot></slot>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

    props: [
      'src',
      'srcXs',
      'srcSm',
      'srcMd',
      'srcLg',
      'srcXl'
    ],

    data () {
      return {
        xs: 0,
        sm: 600,
        md: 1024,
        lg: 1440 - 16,
        xl: 1920 - 16,
        sourceImage: '',
        screenWidth: ''
      }
    },

    computed: {
      bgSrc () {
        if (this.src) {
          return { backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.sourceImage + ')' }
        }
      }
    },

    mounted () {
      let screenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth

      if (screenWidth >= this.xs && screenWidth < this.sm) { this.sourceImage = this.srcXs }
      if (screenWidth >= this.s && screenWidth < this.md) { this.sourceImage = this.srcSm }
      if (screenWidth >= this.md && screenWidth < this.lg) { this.sourceImage = this.srcMd }
      if (screenWidth >= this.lg && screenWidth < this.xl) { this.sourceImage = this.srcLg }
      if (screenWidth >= this.xl) { this.sourceImage = this.srcXl }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The goal is to create a background image for a hero section, but allow for different sized images for different screen sizes.

Here is how an implementation would look:

```
<template>

  <hero-section class="full secondary" 
    src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x270"
    src-xs="http://via.placeholder.com/480x270"
    src-sm="http://via.placeholder.com/720x405"
    src-md="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x810"
    src-lg="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080"
    src-xl="http://via.placeholder.com/2560x1440"
    >
    <v-container fill-height>
      <v-layout column align-center justify-center>
       <!-- TEXT GOES HERE -->
      </v-container>
  </hero-section>  

</template>
```

Am I doing this right, or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: This is better done in CSS.

Comment: @RoyJ I have all the other necessary CSS for the in my stylesheet.  The only change I wish to make is using the Vue Component to load the relevant image rather than use media queries.  My question has to do with whether or not there is a better way to do this via Vue.